# How to get id_token from passport-google-oauth20 package - NestJs

Tags: nestjs, passport-google-oauth

I am new to NestJs and trying to implement `Google Sign in` using `passport-google-oauth20` package. I have followed [that blog](https://dev.to/imichaelowolabi/how-to-implement-login-with-google-in-nest-js-2aoa) to implement google sign in. Through this package I am able to successfully signed-in and able to get `access_token` but I need `id_token` instead of `access_token`. I dug into the `passport-google-oauth20` `Strategy` class and there I can see different overloaded constructors where one overloaded constructor contains params argument of type `GoogleCallbackParameters` which contains optional `id_token` field. But don't know how to make that constructor called. Tried different ways but with no success. :(

Below is my code,

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Request } from "express";
import { Profile } from "passport";
import {
  GoogleCallbackParameters,
  Strategy,
  VerifyCallback,
} from "passport-google-oauth20";
import { googleStrategy } from "src/utils/constants";

@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, "google") {
  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID:
        process.env.BACKEND_ENV === "dev"
          ? googleStrategy.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
          : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret:
        process.env.BACKEND_ENV === "dev"
          ? googleStrategy.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
          : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL:
        process.env.BACKEND_ENV === "dev"
          ? googleStrategy.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL
          : process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
      scope: ["email", "profile", "openid"],
      passReqToCallback: true,
    });
  }

  async validate(
    req: Request,
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    params: GoogleCallbackParameters,
    profile: Profile,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const { name, emails, photos } = profile;
    const user = {
      email: emails[0].value,
      firstName: name.givenName,
      lastName: name.familyName,
      picture: photos[0].value,
      accessToken,
      refreshToken,
    };

    done(null, user);
  }
}
```

As you can see for getting `Request`, I have mentoned `passReqToCallback: true` option and in the validate method I am getting the `Request` object but don't know how to make `params` of type `GoogleCallbackParameters` get filled with the required object.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, hope some one can give an answer

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by passing the callback directly in the super method as a second parameter, I do not why in the validate method it does not work, maybe it is a problem of the passportStrategy that uses nestjs.

Something like below works:

```
@Injectable()
    export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
      constructor() {
        super(
          {
            clientID:
              process.env.BACKEND_ENV === 'dev'
                ? googleStrategy.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
                : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret:
              process.env.BACKEND_ENV === 'dev'
                ? googleStrategy.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
                : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL:
              process.env.BACKEND_ENV === 'dev'
                ? googleStrategy.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL
                : process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
            scope: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
            passReqToCallback: true,
          },
          async (
            req: Request,
            accessToken: string,
            refreshToken: string,
            params: GoogleCallbackParameters,
            profile: Profile,
            done: VerifyCallback,
          ): Promise<any> => {
            const { name, emails, photos } = profile;
            const user = {
              email: emails[0].value,
              firstName: name.givenName,
              lastName: name.familyName,
              picture: photos[0].value,
              accessToken,
              refreshToken,
            };
    
            done(null, user);
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer above by [@miguel-jurado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14857445/miguel-jurado), I would like to add my two cents. In the recent version of Nest and Passport the above might lead to errors. I am using the following versions:

```
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.1.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
```

and using the above code gives me Circular Dependency error. In my case, I just needed to tweak it a little to not include `passReqToCallback` and so overload a different constructor. My code was:

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import {
  GoogleCallbackParameters,
  Profile,
  Strategy,
  VerifyCallback,
} from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
    super(
      {
        clientID: configService.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        clientSecret: configService.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        callbackURL: configService.get('GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL'),
        scope: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
      },
      async (
        accessToken: string,
        refreshToken: string,
        params: GoogleCallbackParameters,
        profile: Profile,
        done: VerifyCallback,
      ) => {
        const {expires_in, id_token} = params;
        const { name, emails, photos } = profile;
        const user = {
          email: emails[0].value,
          firstName: name.givenName,
          lastName: name.familyName,
          picture: photos[0].value,
          accessToken,
          refreshToken,
          id_token,
          expires_in
        };
        done(null, user);
      },
    );
  }
}
```